# passing property key for nested object to a function to return that property value

Tags: javascript

i have a nested object like this

```
const sections = {
   text : {id : 1 , text: 'something' },
   link : {id : 2 , text: 'something' , 'href' : 'http://example.com' },
   social : {
      telegram : {id : 3 , text : 'my telegram' , 'address' : '@mytelegram'} , 
      twitter  : {id : 4 , text : 'my twitter' , 'address' : '@mytwitter'} , 
   }
}
```

i want to have a function giving me each section by passing property key to it

```
function getSection(key ){

   console.log(sections[key]);
}
```

this works for `text` and `link` but if i want `social.telegram` this wont work
is there any way to solve this without some sort of  looping throw sections ?

------------- edit ------------------------

also what if i want to set the value for the `sections` object

something like

```
function setSectionText(key ,  newText)
{
   sections[key].text = newText ; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate the key and get the outer and inner objects until the wanted result.

```js
function getSection(key) {
    return key
        .split('.')
        .reduce((o, k) => o?.[k], sections);
}

const
    sections = { text: { id: 1, text: 'something' }, link: { id: 2, text: 'something', href: 'http://example.com' }, social: { telegram: { id: 3, text: 'my telegram', address: '@mytelegram' }, twitter: { id: 4, text: 'my twitter', address: '@mytwitter' } } };

console.log(getSection('social.telegram'));
getSection('social.telegram').id = 42;
console.log(sections);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thanx , what if i want to store values in the `sections` ?  like sending `id` value to the function alonge with it's property key `(social.telegram)` and store it to `sections.social.telegram.id`

Comment: the function returns the object and with it, you can change `id`, like `getSection('social.telegram').id = 42`. no need for another function.

Comment: yeah but i need to change the `sections` object's value .... changing returned object values has no effect on sections object

Comment: @hretic, please see edit.